# Order By Distance PFQuery

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, sdk

I am using Parse and attempting to run a query where my objects are ordered and sorted by distance along with descending order of a certain ratio:

```
    PFQuery *moreGuysQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [moreGuysQuery whereKey:@"Location" nearGeoPoint:self.currentLocation];
    [moreGuysQuery orderByDescending:@"Ratio"];
```

However, I'm finding that the ratio is taking prescendence and the location is not accounted for. I want the location to also take prescendence.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by just making an array

```
    PFQuery *moreGuysQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByLocation = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:QuoVenueLocation ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByRatio = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:QuoVenueStatsCrowdRatio ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    [moreGuysQuery orderBySortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByLocation, sortByRatio, nil]];
```